# Сохранение Cookie

Tags: jquery, cookie

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить вопрос с сохранением Cookie. Есть код:

**Это рабочая часть**

```
$('.js_selectColor div').on("click", function() {
    $('.js_pro-accordion-menu').removeClass("js_blue js_darkblue js_green js_orange").addClass($(this).attr('class'));
    $.cookie('js_select', 'js_save');
});
```

**Это нерабочая часть:**

```
if ($.cookie('js_select') == 'js_save') {
    $('.js_pro-accordion-menu')дальше не знаю как вывести сохраненный класс, чтобы он присутствовал при переходе на другую страницу;
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы передавался класс, который сохраняется в этой части кода:  `.addClass($(this).attr('class'));`

Comment: А что по-вашему является `$(this)` в нерабочей части?

Comment: Помогите лучше решить вопрос, а не задавать дополнительные. 
Этот кусок кода вырезал с предыдущего. Вот не знаю, как вытащить сохраненный класс с него. Помочь можете?

Comment: @jsp, я спросил, потому что было непонятно, ошибка это или недостаточный кусок кода, да и изначально не ясно было из вопроса, что речь идёт о разных страницах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте выводить нужный класс через Cookie:

```
$('.js_selectColor div').on("click", function() {
    var classActive = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.js_pro-accordion-menu').removeClass("js_blue js_darkblue js_green js_orange").addClass(classActive);
    $.cookie('js_select', 'js_save');
    $.cookie('js_class', classActive);
});
```

И на другой странице:

```
if ($.cookie('js_select') == 'js_save') {
    $('.js_pro-accordion-menu').addClass($.cookie('js_class'));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('.js_selectColor div').on("click", function() {
var lol = $(this).attr('class');
        $('.js_pro-accordion-menu').removeClass("js_blue js_darkblue js_green js_orange").addClass(lol);
        $.cookie('js_select', 'js_save');
    });
```

Вот так попробуйте

Comment: Как вывести сохраненный класс при переходе на другую страницу?

    if ($.cookie('js_select') == 'js_save') {
        $('.js_pro-accordion-menu') дальше не знаю что писать...
    }